# PHP Prepared statement returning wrong value

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to find out if a user exists in my database already, but no matter what I try, I always get the equivalent of a false.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();

if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    return 'user exists';
}
```

I know this has got to be something very simple... something I am clearly overlooking, but I always get that num_rows = 0, even though the user is in the database already.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `get_result()` or `store_result()` before call `num_rows`:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_username = ?");    
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result(); //<--- HERE

if($res->num_rows > 0) { //<--- HERE
    return 'user exists';
}
```

OR

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result(); //<--- HERE

if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
```

Comment: Perfect.... When I do the first (which I did try before), I get Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result(). But I didn't try the store_result, and that works. Do you know why I get that error when I try get_result?

Comment: That's odd. It's documented here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: @Apolymoxic `get_result()` is only available if you have the `mysqlnd` driver.